# How to pull next text into input element

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

This is my situation:

[image: no change]

#hours is id of input element.

After changing style like below, in Firefox, the result is desirable, but int Chrome 'Hours' get below of input and is not visible. Note that I can not put 'Hours' inside `<span>` or other elements and can not make input element transparent!

```
#hours {
    margin-right: -4.5em;
}
```

[image: after negative margin]

Is it possible to show in Chrome like Firefox?

#Edit ------------------------------------------------

P.S:
What is difference between "Behind" and "Front" in chrome?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the `input` element in a new `div` and set the `div` style to:

```
position: relative;
```

and the `#hours` style to:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
margin-right: -4.5em;
```